# FlatList item to image in React Native

Tags: react-native, syntax

I'm trying to loop across a JSON and for each item load an image but I get a syntax error.

```
const WizardContainer = props => {
    ImagePathItems = [
        { path: '../../resources/svg/wizard-r.png', txtValue: "1" },
        { path: '../../resources/svg/wizard-c.png', txtValue: "2" },
        { path: '../../resources/svg/wizard-s.png', txtValue: "3" },
        { path: '../../resources/svg/wizard-d.png', txtValue: "4" }];
    return (
        <View style={styles.a}>
            <View style={styles.b}>
                <View style={styles.c}>
                    <FlatList
                        horizontal
                        data={ImagePathItems}
                        renderItem={({ item }) =>
                            <Image
                                style={styles.tinyLogo}
                                //source={require('../../resources/svg/wizard-d.png')}
                                source={require({ item.path })} //SYNTAX ERROR
                            />
                        }
                        keyExtractor={item => item.txtValue}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

export default WizardContainer;
```

If I discomment the previous line load the image fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ImagePathItems` array and `Image` source as well like this

```
const WizardContainer = props => {
ImagePathItems = [
    { path: require('../../resources/svg/wizard-r.png'), txtValue: "1" },
    { path: require('../../resources/svg/wizard-c.png'), txtValue: "2" },
    { path: require('../../resources/svg/wizard-s.png'), txtValue: "3" },
    { path: require('../../resources/svg/wizard-d.png'), txtValue: "4" }];
return (
    <View style={styles.a}>
        <View style={styles.b}>
            <View style={styles.c}>
                <FlatList
                    horizontal
                    data={ImagePathItems}
                    renderItem={({ item }) =>
                        <Image
                            style={styles.tinyLogo}
                            source={item.path}
                        />
                    }
                    keyExtractor={item => item.txtValue}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
   );
};

export default WizardContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting require in the data object:

```
{path: require('../../resources/svg/wizard-r.png'), txtValue: 1}
```

And then in your code, you can just reference as

```
<Image source={(item.path)} />
```

Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `require` with variables because jsbundler is running in build-time, it can't figure out which modules to bundle when the name is a dynamic variable.

So if you really want to use variable to import path with require you can use a syntax like [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/require.context#examplejs). Adding partial statiic string to `require` can make it work.

```
var restOfThePath = 'svg/wizard-r.png'

require('../../resources/' + restOfThePath)
```

Or you can just `require` them in an object then use the object in your code.

Also using `{` inside your `require` is the reason why you have a syntax error. If you remove it then error will go away.

.
.

```
const WizardContainer = props => {
    ImagePathItems = [
        { path: require('../../resources/svg/wizard-r.png'), txtValue: "1" },
        { path: ('../../resources/svg/wizard-c.png'), txtValue: "2" },
        { path: ('../../resources/svg/wizard-s.png'), txtValue: "3" },
        { path: ('../../resources/svg/wizard-d.png'), txtValue: "4" }];
    return (
        <View style={styles.a}>
            <View style={styles.b}>
                <View style={styles.c}>
                    <FlatList
                        horizontal
                        data={ImagePathItems}
                        renderItem={({item}) =>
                            <Image
                                style={styles.tinyLogo}
                                source={item.path}
                            />
                        }
                        keyExtractor={item => item.txtValue}
                    />
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

export default WizardContainer;
```